# How to add "Pending Changes" button to toolbar in VS 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I would like to be able to access the "Pending Changes" button directly from the toolbar in Visual Studio 2010 without having to click down a submenu.

I know how to add buttons to the toolbars, but I cannot seem to find the "Pending Changes" button in the Customize Window.

I found something called "Pending Checkins" but that seems to be something different.

Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Found it.  It's under View --> tfsPendingChanges.

You can also find tfsSourceControlExplorer and tfsHistory.

So I made a new toolbar for just those items.